# How to merger this sql server query?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this query

```
select count(*) as COUNT_A, datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan]) as [year]
from [table_name] 
where Sertifikat_Nomor IS NOT NULL
group by datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan])
```

and this

```
select count(*) as COUNT_B, datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan]) as [year]
from [table_name] 
where Sertifikat_Nomor IS NULL
group by datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan])
```

The difference is only `IS NOT NULL` and `IS NULL` and the result is

`+---------+--------+
| COUNT_A  |  year  |
+----------+--------+
| 12       | 1991   |
| 15       | 1993   |
| 24       | 1998   |
+----------+--------+`

I want make like this

`+---------+---------+--------+
| COUNT_A  | COUNT_B |  year  |
+----------+---------+--------+
| 12       | 23      | 1991   |
| 15       | 33      | 1993   |
| 24       | 13      | 1998   |
+----------+---------+--------+`

and I try like this

```
select (select count(*) as COUNT_A, datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan]) as [year] 
from [table_name]
where Sertifikat_Nomor IS NOT NULL
group by datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan])), 
(select count(*) as COUNT_B, datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan]) as [year]
from [table_name] 
where Sertifikat_Nomor IS NULL
group by datepart(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan]))
```

But didn't fix my problem.
I have use `CASE WHEN`, but still didn't fix the problem.
How to merge and fix their?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN ertifikat_Nomor IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_A,
SUM(CASE WHEN Sertifikat_Nomor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS COUNT_B,
DATEPART(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan]) AS [year]
FROM[table_name] 
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, [Tgl_Perolehan])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using co-related subquery

```
SELECT   Datepart(yyyy, o.[Tgl_Perolehan]) AS [Tgl_Perolehan] , 
         ( 
                SELECT Count(*) 
                FROM   [table_name] i 
                WHERE  i.<somid> = o.<somid> 
                AND    i.sertifikat_nomor  IS NOT NULL ) AS AS count_a , 
         ( 
                SELECT count(*) 
                FROM   [table_name] ii 
                WHERE  ii.<somid> = o.<somid> 
                AND    ii.sertifikat_nomor IS NULL) AS AS count_b 
FROM     [table_name] o 
GROUP BY datepart(yyyy,o.[Tgl_Perolehan])
```

Comment: what `<somid>` mean? and have an error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

Comment: <Some Id> means a unique id which identifies record uniquely ,like Primary key column